# Sinatra & HAML: auto-escape/convert unsafe HTML characters for a whole template?

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, haml

I've got a little sinatra app I'm using to run a basic website.  The content for said site is being provided by a client, and most of it is coming out of PDFs.  Since I'd rather not have to manually replace all the `<` with `&lt;`, and the `&` with `&amp;`, is there a way to configure HAML/Sinatra to do it for me automatically?

Basically, I have some blocks that look like this:

```
%p
  large block of text here...
  multi-line so I can see it in my IDE...
  more lines here...
```

I'd like to just find some config option that tells HAML to go through all of the content and replace unsafe characters with their HTML entity counterparts.

I tried using the HTMLEntities gem, but this site has a lot of multi-line paragraphs, and I couldn't seem to get it to work.  By that I mean that I would do something like this in my `server.rb` file:

```
def "/some_url"
  @encoder = HTMLEntities.new
  haml :some_template
end
```

And in my template:

```
%p
  = @encoder.encode("Really long multiline string...
    some more lines here...
    and more lines...")
```

And it would spit out an error about missing a closing `)`.

Comment: What did you not get to work? Do you mean the `<p>` tags get escaped although you didn't want them to? Please show us the code where you tried to use the HTMLEntities gem.

Comment: Is the input actually physically written into the HAML file, or is it loaded dynamically? An minimal failing example with a Sinatra route + template + view would be useful.

Comment: Sorry.  The content is physically written into the HAML file–this is a "brochure"/flat website, so there's no CMS or anything injecting content.

By "Not working," I mean that I can't seem to wrap the HTMLEntities::encode() block around the multi-line content blocks.  I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`:escaped` filter](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaped-filter):

```haml
%p
  :escaped
    A block of text here that might
    contain & and <.
```

output:

```html
<p>
  A block of text here that might
  contain &amp; and &lt;.
</p>
```

It’s not quite automatic, but might reduce the editing required.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI::escapeHTML('unsafe string <script>kill() && destroy()</script>'
#=> "unsafe string &lt;script&gt;kill() &amp;&amp; destroy()&lt;/script&gt;"
```

### EDIT

Now i actually get what you want. Just use `:escape_html => true` and you can wrap your text in `='...text here...'` because all strings are implicitly escaped.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  haml :index, :escape_html => true
end

__END__

@@layout
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Example
  %body
    = yield

@@index
%p
  ='Here is some <em>unsafe</em> HTML.'
  ='<script type="text/javascript">'
  ='killKittens() && destroyHumanity()'
  ='</script>'
```

Result:

```
$ curl localhost:4567
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Here is some &lt;em&gt;unsafe&lt;/em&gt; HTML.
      &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
      killKittens() &amp;&amp; destroyHumanity()
      &lt;/script&gt;
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For whatever reasons, with a vanilla up-to-date setup, this will render escaped characters even without `escape_html: true` :(